# How to suppress SonarQube rule on import-statement?

Tags: sonarqube

I'm trying to suppress a rule on an import

```
import com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPMessage;
```

apparently doing the following on the class does not work

```
@SuppressWarnings("squid:S1191")
```

any suggestions? Using SonarQube 5.3

Answer (score 3):

Answering my own question. Just add a //NOSONAR comment to the line.

```
import com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPMessage; //NOSONAR
```

Comment: What do you if sonarlint is giving you a warning for using //NOSONAR?